# How can I evaluate constants and macros in the correct order, when I don't want my constant to be treated as one argument?

Tags: c

I'm getting an error that I'm not passing enough arguments to my C Macro, which makes sense, because it's evaluating the macro before a constant I passed it, which is actually supposed to substitute into multiple arguments. What is the best way to fix this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYMACRO(a,b,c) ((a)*(b)*(c))
#define MYCONSTANT 3,4

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", MYMACRO(2, MYCONSTANT));
}
```

The output is irrelevant to the question. I would just like to know what constitutes the order of `#define` evaluation.

Comment: This is not C for starters.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What is wrong with his question?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte: `#include <iostream>` and `std :: cout` are C++ code and are not C code, but the question is tagged C and is not tagged C++. C and C++ are increasingly different. I do not know if the rules have diverged much yet in the “preprocessing” features, but, even if they have not, a suitable solution might be different in C++ than in C because, for example, there may be compile-time constant features in C++ that are not available in C. The question should be tagged with the single language the OP wants an answer for. (If they want both, they should ask a separate question.)

Comment: Is there a reason why did you tagged this C when it is clearly C++?

Comment: Regardless, for C you can define another macro taking two parameters `#define MYMACRO1(a, b) MYMACRO(a, b)` and then "calling" it instead `MYMACRO1(2, MYCONSTANT);`

Comment: (a) Do not play games with the preprocessor. It is a holdover from the Before Times and should mostly be used only for simple substitutions that are clear to the reader and do not cause confusion or rely on weird processing of macros. (b) Give more context for what you are really trying to do; simplifying it to `MyConstant` with a constant `3,4` that is actually two constants, not one, is confusing and fails to demonstrate what the actual goal is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If the tag is the problem then ask like this nice gentleman did. But I see now thanks ;D

Comment: @BernardoDuarte: I did not complain. You asked a question, and I gave you an answer with plenty of information and explanation so that you would understand the issues involved.

Comment: @EricPostpischil _Do not play games with the preprocessor_ Amen to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro arguments are not expanded at the call, but in the replacement.

You need an additional level of macro to let it expand the argument. The names in my suggestion are chosen from the number of arguments, but you might want to use other names.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYMACRO3(a,b,c) ((a)*(b)*(c))
#define MYMACRO2(a,b) MYMACRO3(a,b)
#define MYCONSTANT 3,4

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", MYMACRO2(2, MYCONSTANT));
}
```

But as others say, simply avoid preprocessor magic. It will give you all kinds of headaches.